# Does F# has special syntax for Range and Index types?

Tags: f#

In C# we can use `start..end` or `start..^fromEnd` syntax for creating [`Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.range?view=netcore-3.1) value.

In F# we can create enumerable ranges with `{start..stop}` or `{start..step..stop}` which are similar to what is returned by [`Enumerable.Range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.range?view=netcore-3.1).

But is there any special syntax for [defining ranges and indices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/ranges-indexes)?

Comment: Is slicing what your after https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/slices or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is supported (to a certain extent)  in F# 5.0 preview. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-f-5-preview-1/